# insert_from over two databases

Tags: mysql, peewee

I try to move all rows from one database table (source) to another database (target). The source-DB is a local database while target-DB runs on another machine. I want to transfer rows between the two databases and found the [Model.insert_from()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.insert_from) method for that task. Unfortunately it does nothing and I can't find any reason for that.

The database model is:

```
databaseSource = MySQLDatabase('sourceDB', **{'host': 'localhost', 'user': 'local', 'password': ''})

databaseTarget = MySQLDatabase('targetDB', **{'host': 'externalserver', 'user': 'external', 'password': ''})

class BaseModelSource(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = databaseSource
class BaseModelTarget(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = databaseTarget

class UsersSource(BaseModelSource):
    crdate = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL("DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")])
    description = TextField()
    firstName = CharField(column_name='first_name')

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'users'

class UsersTarget(BaseModelTarget):
    crdate = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL("DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")])
    description = TextField()
    firstName = CharField(column_name='first_name')

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'users'
```

With that my task should run with:

```
import peewee
from dbmodels import *

dataQuery = UsersSource.select(
    UsersSource.crdate, 
    UsersSource.description,
    UsersSource.firstName)

insertQuery = UsersTarget.insert_from(dataQuery,[
    UsersTarget.crdate, 
    UsersTarget.description,
    UsersTarget.firstName]).execute()
```

The resulting MySQL-query is this and as you can see, the selected data is empty []:

```
('INSERT INTO `users` (`crdate`, `description`, `first_name`) SELECT `t1`.`crdate`, `t1`.`description`, `t1`.`first_name` FROM `users` AS `t1`', [])
```

When I run the SELECT query on my table it outputs:

```
SELECT `t1`.`crdate`, `t1`.`description`, `t1`.`first_name` FROM `users` AS `t1`;


2018-08-12 16:50:36 valid   Heinz
2018-08-12 19:34:45 valid   Hilde
2018-08-12 19:33:31 invalid Paul
```

I searched like hell but didn't find any hint, why my result is empty.

Does anybody know more or a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peewee cannot insert data between two different database servers/connections. If both databases are on the same server, however, you can use the "schema" Meta option to reference each database from a single connection, and do the INSERT FROM that way:

```
db = MySQLDatabase('my_db')

class UsersSource(Model):
    crdate = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL("DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")])
    description = TextField()
    firstName = CharField(column_name='first_name')

    class Meta:
        database = db
        schema = 'source_db_name'
        table_name = 'users'

class UsersTarget(Model):
    crdate = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL("DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")])
    description = TextField()
    firstName = CharField(column_name='first_name')

    class Meta:
        database = db
        schema = 'dest_db_name'
        table_name = 'users'
```

If the databases are on different servers, then you have no other option but to dump it and reload it.

Comment: Thank you for the hint regarding "schema". Even when it won't solve my problem, it's useful later.

I'll do a dump of the source table and try the peewee db.execute_sql() and insert the dump with it.

Comment: Glad that clarified the issue. I'd strongly suggest you just use the mysql tooling to handle dumping and restoring, for what it's worth. There's literally no reason you should use peewee for that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off operation I recommend using `mysqldump` and then copying the file to the remote server and sourcing the dumped files with the `mysql` client.

If this needs to be a continual process look at MySQL replication.

To batch transfer it you'll need to iterate over the result set of the `SELECT` and put this into the `INSERT` statement as they are on different servers.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and the hint to the mysql replication.

I'll try the db.execute_sql() to insert the dump.